# Removing empty line before enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, tabu

I've got a `tabu`table with two columns, one of which is supposed to contain a list:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \setenumerate{topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt} % Doesn't work
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{X[0.5]X[0.5]}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item[] Should be on the same line as B
  \item[] \ldots
  \end{enumerate}
& 
B
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to remove the empty line that is apparently inserted before the `enumerate`environment. I've tried playing with the `enumitem`options but haven't had any success. I'd like to avoid adding negative `vspace`if possible.

Comment: Perhaps  `multicol` typesetting  is better than a table in this case?

Comment: I'm using this inside a table. I basically want to separate the contents of the table cell by empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the `enumerate` environment inside a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt} % Doesn't work
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{X[0.5]X[0.5]}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Should be on the same line as B
  \item \ldots
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
& 
B
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]